# GlassFish duplicando diretório

Tags: java, glassfish

Ao salvar uma foto, em vez de criar o diretório acaba duplicando, aparentemente ele coloca o primeiro diretório do servidor Glassfish e no outro o que eu havia citado, por ser leigo não estou conseguindo identificar o erro, conseguem enxergar o erro?

> Erro ao envir arquivo: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\gfalc\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\GF_4.1.1\domain1\generated\jsp\LojaGames\C:\Users\gfalc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LojaGames\build\web....\web\img\2833f90d2c3fecee171be3db379b30bc.jpeg (A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do volume está incorreta)

```
    String SAVE_DIR = "/../../web/img";//Glassfish

public String[] up(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException {
    String[] fileName = null, tipo = null;
    try {

        String appPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("");


        String savePath = appPath + SAVE_DIR;


        System.out.println("Aplicativo path:" + savePath);


        File saveDir = new File(savePath);
        if (!saveDir.exists()) {
            saveDir.mkdir();
        }
        //Cria uma lista de nome de arquivos
        fileName = new String[request.getParts().size()];
        int x = 0;

        //Varre todos os campos do formulario e pega apenas os arquivos de foto
        for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            if (part.getSubmittedFileName() != null) {
                tipo = part.getContentType().split("/");
                if (tipo[1].length() <= 4) {
                    fileName[x] = br.com.lojagames.util.Crypt.md5(part.getSubmittedFileName()) + "." + tipo[1];
                    part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName[x]);
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Qual a saída do sysout, dessa impressão?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Aplicativo path:C:\Users\gfalc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LojaGames\build\web/../../web/img

Comment: bem, a mensagem de erro aponta já para o arquivo com nome temporário. Na saída colada, vi duas coisas estranhas: (a) ele ignorou as barras / que você pôs; (b) ele tá colocando `C:\\` duas vezes, como se você estivesse concatenando o path do temporário com o diretório de salvar, não usando o diretório de salvar como absoluto

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ele ignorar as barras não me incomoda tanto, o problema é ele duplicar o C:, e não estou conseguindo configurar :(

Comment: eu diria que seu erro está mais adiante, pouco tem a ver com isso aí. Ignorar as barras para mim é sinal de alerta máximo, pois significa ignorar sua árvore de diretórios. Enfim, onde ele está tentando abrir o arquivo para salvar a foto enviada?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado coloquei no post a continuação, se puder dar uma olhada agradeço

Comment: dentro do `if`, pode imprimir individualmente os valores de `savePath`, `x`, `fileName[x]`? Logo antes de dar o `part.write`

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado perdão a demora, estou trabalhando no projeto. Sim, me retornou o seguinte: _Informações:   Aplicativo path:C:\Users\gfalc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LojaGames\build\web\..\..\web\img
Informações:   Aplicativo x:0
Informações:   Aplicativo fileName[x]:696e0e5d8ab24c4af029ac2fb5eccc6a.jpeg_

Comment: Não consigo enxergar como ele gerou aquele path estranho =\ Vamos esperar que alguém mais capaz consiga ajudar

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Rapaz, nem eu ahuahua. Tentei até dar um .replace() mas nada certo. Muito obrigado pelo seu tempo e sua ajuda.